# Can blocks in Minecraft have right-click actions, such as tossing an ender pearl?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So I've been trying to make the Space Stone from the Marvel universe and I would like to know whether it's possible to make it so that when I right click a block of blue glazed terra-cotta, an ender pearl can be tossed or some action can take place. If possible, I would also like the block to leave water particles behind me. Is there any way to make sure of this with command lingo?

Comment: You mean holding a block as item and clicking? No, that would always attempt to place the block and either do it or fail completely. But you could retexture a different item. For example… an ender pearl!

Answer (score 0):

[There is a way to have custom right-click actions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/227112/188492). The following is taken from that answer (see that for info on how it works), except edited to be relevant to this answer and updated for 1.13:

> First run the following commands once to create the scoreboard objectives used:
>
> 1. `/scoreboard objectives add holdTerracotta dummy`
> 2. `/scoreboard objectives add rightClick dummy`
> 3. `/scoreboard objectives add summoned dummy`
>
> Create a command block chain that runs the following commands in the correct order:
>
> 1. `scoreboard players add @a summoned 0`
> 2. `scoreboard players set @a holdTerracotta 0`
> 3. `scoreboard players set @a[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:blue_glazed_terracotta"}] holdTerracotta 1`
> 4. `scoreboard players set @e[type=armor_stand] rightClick 0`
> 5. `scoreboard players set @e[type=armor_stand,nbt={HandItems:[{id:"minecraft:blue_glazed_terracotta"]}] rightClick 1`
> 6. `execute as @e[type=armor_stand,scores={rightClick=1..}] run <summon ender pearl command>`
> 7. `execute at @e[scores={holdSword=1..,summoned=0}] run summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:rightclick,Invisible:1b,Invulnerable:1b,NoBasePlate:1b,NoGravity:1b,ShowArms:1b}`
> 8. `scoreboard players set @a[scores={holdSword=1..,summoned=0}] summoned 1`
> 9. `execute as @a[scores={holdSword1..,summoned=1..}] at @s run tp @e[type=armor_stand,name=rightclick,distance=..1] @s`
> 10. `execute at @a[scores={holdSword=0,summoned=1..}] kill @e[type=armor_stand,name=rightclick,distance=..1]`
> 11. `give @a[scores={holdSword=0,summoned=1..}] blue_glazed_terracotta`
> 12. `scoreboard players set @a[scores={holdSword=0,summoned1..}] summoned 0`

<sup>I haven't tested any of this.</sup>

However, the part about summoning an ender pearl (I'm assuming so it's as if an ender pearl was thrown normally) is beyond my knowledge and capabilties. You could try looking at [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/MinecraftCommands/comments/c1j36k/help_summoning_ender_pearls).