# How to test for people standing on a specific block?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to set up a trap for my friend on my server, I want to use command blocks, not tripwire.

I know the `/testfor` command, but it always says that it found me and doesn't give another output.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the `execute` command.

1. Setup a full clock. I recommend the answer to [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/227011/how-do-i-make-a-setblock-or-a-fill-clock) if you need to know how.
2. On one side of that red stone block, put down a new command block with this command in it:

`Execute Notch ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-1 ~ grass 0 <command>`

Replace notch with your friend's name, replace grass with the block name you want him to be standing on, and replace command with the command you want to do.

Comment: What do I do with the cords, just put them in? Or do they have to have the tildas?

Comment: @PeoplePerson Tildes need to be there, as it's executing at his exact position (the tilde will represent his exact coordinate) to detect the block under him.

Comment: If you want the trap to catch any player, replace `Notch` with `@a`. Note that this will execute the command at *any* player standing on the block, so using a common block like grass is likely to cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

For get an output, you have to put a comparator in front of the command block. When it finds you, the comparator should emit a redstone pulse that will activate whatever you want.

Comment: This does not answer the question. He had the problem of the command block finding him and not his friend