# Testing for structures near players

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to have a redstone timer that has a signal into a command block, with `/execute @a ~ ~ ~ testforblocks <Coordinate 1> <Coordinate 2> <Relative Position>` and then a compartor, testing if a structure 1 X away from the player (I may make it 2) is the same as a structure I built somewhere else. (A chest with a sign on top of it reading “[Case]” and then having 2 iron blocks next to the chest) Then, the chest will fill with random loot, and the iron and sign disappear. I know how to do the random loot, and how to make the blocks disappear, but using `/execute` will only test if A player is next to the structure. How do I tell the players that are near the structure from the players that aren't?

Comment: That would require 1 comand block for every block in the structure to test against it. And this will be much easier now with the latest snapshot (with conditional chain command blocks with testfor) If you know the location of the structure, then just testfor location instead. From the sounds of it, you want to use a `/testfor @a[x=nx , y=ny , z=nz, r=radius] ` where nx, ny, nz is the location center of the area you want to test for presence, and r is the radius out from <nx, ny, nz> that you want to test in.

Answer (score 1):

Note: this Answer is based off the assumption that you are making that structure using a command or making it yourself. Sorry if this is not correct.

**A) Marking the structure:**

First, whenever that structure is spawned, summon an armorstand in one of those blocks with the NBT tags Invisible, CustomName and Marker. (Ex. `/summon ArmorStand x y z {Marker:1b, Invisible:1b, CustomName:bob}`)

**B) marking the player as near the structure:**

Make a  dummy scoreboard (example name:nearS) Now add this command to a 20 t/s clock: `execute @a ~ ~ ~ execute @e[type=ArmorStand,name=bob,r=1] ~ ~ ~ scoreboard players set @p nearS 1` and this command also on that clock: `scoreboard players set @a nearS 0` ([making 20 tick/s clock](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/227012/118457))
Then, you can distinguish which players are near it and which are not by their number on the scoreboard nearS.

Comment: I am having a player build it anywhere in the world, and testing it from a pre-made structure, so an armor stand probably wouldn't work...

Comment: But thank you for the answer :D