# Vanilla Minecraft - Detect various /trigger outputs

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

On multiplayer in Minecraft, I am trying to detect when a player changes their score using /trigger. Here's an example scenario:

I create a new objective called "test." Then, I use `/scoreboard players enable @a test`, which lets everyone modify the objective.
After which, I have a /tellraw command used on all players giving them four options to click. Each option corresponds to a different score the player gives themselves. For example, clicking on "test one" would make the player run `/trigger test set 1`, clicking on "test two" would make them run `/trigger test set 2`, and so on.

How would I be able to detect when a player set their objective to a specific number score, such as 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use scoreboard in player selectors to find out which one they clicked. Usually this is done by either `testfor` or `execute`.

I recommend a 20 t/s clock to check these as soon as they click it. You don't have to use one, but it may help. [great method to setup one.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/227012/118457)

**In the case of testfor**, it is actually not recommended to use it. You can't exactly distinguish which player clicked it, you just know that it was clicked. A better way is the execute method. Never-the-less, the command should look like this:

```
Testfor @a[score_test=1,score_test_min=1]
```

You will need a comparator to get if it succeeded to find it. You should also have a separate command block for each, then change the `1` to another number for each possible outcome.

**In the case of execute:** recommended method. You can use @p in the `command` part to target that specific player. Command as follows:

```
Execute @a[score_test=1,score_test_min=1] ~ ~ ~ <command>
```

For this, you should set their score of that to 0 as soon as the command is run, otherwise that command may be run twice.

Comment: Another problem with the testfor method is that this is a multiplayer server, so the comparator would not be able to detect many clicks at once. My question is, does /execute even allow non-op players to use commands that require op?

Comment: @Draconwolver sorry, I mean that the command need to be in a command block. The trigger command will change the score, this command only detects it and runs a command when someone clicks it.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I'm wording this correctly. What I mean to ask is, if you run /execute in a command block like you're saying, will the command you put in be run as OP?

Comment: @Draconwolver oh, ok. It is actually run at the server-level, which is above OP. It can do everything OP can. The only thing command blocks can't do is use the commands KICK and OP.