# How can I summon a mob with an always-visible name tag?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

My son would like to know how to summon a mob with an always-visible name tag.

He's tried `CustomNameVisible:1` but it doesn't work.  It summons the mob, but the name tag is only visible when you look at the creature.

Comment: `CustomNameVisible:1` should work. What is the exact command he is typing in?

Comment: We read somewhere that the command no longer works for mobs, only items?  This is what he types:

/summon Zombie ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:"Zorp",CustomNameVisible:1}

But the mob name is only visible when looking right at it and within a certain range.

Comment: That command should work, and does in the latest snapshots. Seems to be a problem with 1.8.8 that it doesn't work in it.

Comment: Yeah, you (or your son) seem to be doing everything correctly.  Is there possibly a range limitation that still applies to `CustomNameVisible` that doesn't apply to `CustomName` and the cursor?

Answer (score 3):

In Minecraft 1.8, the `CustomNameVisible` tag only works on Armor Stand entities.

Here is a workaround for putting a tag on a mob. Actually it isn't really on the mob itself, but on an Armor Stand riding it.

```
/summon ArmorStand ~ ~1 ~ {CustomName:"YourNameHere",CustomNameVisible:1,Small:1,Invisible:1,Invulnerable:1,Riding:{id:"EntityNameHere"}}
```

You just have to replace `YourNameHere` by the tag you want to appear and `EntityNameHere` by the entity name (e.g. `Zombie` or `Skeleton`).

Answer (score 2):

It seems like it may be a bug in Minecraft 1.8.8, or maybe a removed feature. There is a way to overcome it though. It may be hard to do, but if it is really a required feature this is the only way I can think of doing it.

Create a clock ([click here for a tutorial on how to make a fast clock](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/227011/how-do-i-make-a-setblock-or-a-fill-clock)). Add a command block to the clock with the following command:

```
/tp @e[type=ArmorStand,name=NAMEHERE] @e[type=!ArmorStand,name=NAMEHERE]
```

Then run the following command once:

```
/summon ArmorStand ~ ~ ~ {Invisible:1,Invulnerable:1,CustomName:NAMEHERE,CustomNameVisible:1}
```

Just replace `NAMEHERE` with the name you want, in your case replace `NAMEHERE` with `Zorp`.

This works because the `ArmorStand` entity will always have it's name visible above it if it has the `CustomNameVisible:1` tag. It is supposed to work on other entities too, but for some reason it doesn't, which I don't know why.